# Grails AsyncHttpBuilder configuration

Tags: json, http, asynchronous, grails, slack

I'm creating a service in Grails 3 to post a json request to a slack webhook an tried with

`compile 'org.grails.plugins:async-http-builder:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'`

however with this code

```
import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
import grails.http.client.*
import grails.async.*


@Transactional
class NotificacionService {

    def enviarSlack() {
        AsyncHttpBuilder client = new AsyncHttpBuilder()
        Promise<HttpClientResponse> p = client.post("https://localhost:8080/foo/bar") {
            contentType 'application/json'
            json {
                title "Ping"
            }
        }
        p.onComplete { HttpClientResponse resp ->
            log.debug resp.json
        }
    }
}
```

I get a Cannot resolve symbol 'AsyncHttpBuilder'

Any hints or other ways to accomplish the same?

Comment: Do you specifically need it to be asynchronous?

Comment: I already have it working sync’ly I wanted to try it the other way